# Can't see tree when using $tree in django mac terminal

Tags: django, macos, terminal, tree

Whenever I try to see my files using $tree, nothing happens.

Here is a picture of the code I'm trying to run.

[image: Here is a picture of the code im trying to run.]

And here is what it is supposed to return.

[image: And here is what it is supposed to return.]

But as you can see in the first picture, nothing shows up.

I can see it in my finder but just not in the terminal which is weird as well.

[image: I can see it in my finder but just not in the terminal which is weird]

Answer (score 0):

The $ in front of UNIX commands is meant to indicate running a command as a user. Just run `tree`; you may need to install it with `brew install tree`

Comment: I have installed it and nothing works.